# Matrix-like printing of 2D arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, printing, numpy, 2d

Say I have a matrix in a numpy array in Python

```
In [3]: my_matrix
Out[3]: 
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
         2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]])
```

Is there a way to have Python/IPython print my array as:

```
[ 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2; 
  0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ]
```

? (~ similar to the way MATLAB does it)

Also, I have noticed that IPython does **not** use the full width of my terminal when printing `numpy` arrays. Other functions do (e.g. `pprint.pprint`). How can I change that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [numpy.set_printoptions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html). For increasing the line width:

```
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=150)
```

Replace 150 by whatever you need. Now, to print as you asked (I guess it means without the decimal point):

```
print my_matrix.astype('i')
```

If you have floating point values you can also control the precision for printouts with the option `precision`:

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
```